# Can I take the seeds of the plant Strychnos nux vomica out of its packet with bare hands and sow them in my farm with bare hands?

Tags: plant-recommendations, seeds

Can I take the seeds of the plant Strychnos nux vomica out of its packet with bare hands and sow them in my farm with bare hands? Or they(i. e., the seeds) would cause me a poisonous effect due to touching with bare hands? Or if the gardening gloves are to be used, then which type of gardening gloves should I use to sow them?

Answer (score 1):

I would wear gloves, probably latex ones so you can still feel the seeds properly, just as a precaution, but although the seeds are posionous, capable of producing strychnine, they have to be macerated during processing, or masticated (chewed) and swallowed before the strychnine can affect your spinal column, so in theory, you should be safe to handle them without gloves or protection. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/pharmacology-toxicology-and-pharmaceutical-science/strychnos-nux-vomica